# sporadic SQL query times using pyodbc python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm connecting to a SQL database using python, and below is roughly what the code looks like:

```
# connect to db using connection string
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# execute SQL query
code = "select bid, ask from Option where call_put = 'P' and 
        tdate between '2010-01-01' and '2018-01-01' "

# this is the line taking time
cursor.execute(code).fetchallnumpy()
```

Couple problems I'm experiencing are ;

1) the SQL query times range from 0.5 seconds to 5 minutes for the same code,  sometimes I restart the kernel and it works fine, others not so much

2) The problem goes away if I do a 2 year range for the 'BETWEEN', but when I try to do a longer range I get the slow down

note: the .mdf file is on the D:\

note2: actually using 'turbodbc', not 'pydobc' (but problem persists in both)

note3: data has 1 billion rows

Comment: Is the table indexed?

Comment: @IainShelvington it says "PK_OptionValue (Clustered)" under "Indexes"

Comment: @IainShelvington and then as "Index key columns" there are 5, with 'tdate' and 'call_put' both in there

Comment: Try creating a covering index that includes all the fields mentioned in the query.  This may take a while to build on a 1 billion record table, but when finished the performance should be greatly improved.

Comment: @alexherm im not too familiar with SQL, what would be the difference between that and current struct ? what do you think is causing the slow down and how would covering index help . thanks

Comment: With a covering index in place your query should make use of the index and run much faster.  If you can run an explain plan from database IDE you will surely find its doing a full table scan.  After the index is in place it should use the index.  You may want to get your DBA or DB developer involved..

Comment: @thomas.mac - If `call_put` is an `nvarchar` column then try using `... where call_put = N'P' ...`